# Handle and propagate SIGHUP signal to child process without parent termination

Tags: linux, bash, signals

I've got a piece of classic problem, but can't figure out how to deal with it. There is a bash process which executes children, and I want to send some signal to it (SIGHUP), handle it there and propagate this signal to one of the children (another_long_running_process for example). Here is snippet:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

long_running_process &
another_long_running_process &
pid=$!

trap 'kill -1 $pid' HUP

wait $pid
```

Ok, now I setup trap, create handler to send signal to particular pid, but then find out that my script just exits after first SIGHUP receiving and handling. The problem that bash returns immediately from wait built-in:

> When Bash receives a signal for which a trap has been set while waiting for a command to complete, the trap will not be executed until the command completes. When Bash is waiting for an asynchronous command via the wait built-in, the reception of a signal for which a trap has been set will cause the wait built-in to return immediately with an exit status greater than 128, immediately after which the trap is executed.

And yes, my script just exits after first time I send SIGHUP, by design. But I need to keep it running.

And I can't figure out how to wait children processes, and propagate one of them (ok, even all of them) SIGHUP signals multiple times while they're running. Is this achievable in such problem definition? I think with parent pid I can iterate over children and find required process and then send signal particularly there, but it looks a bit overengineering, or not?

Comment: Instead of bothering with propagating signals (itself quite a lousy idea imho), you could just `pkill -P pid_of_the_script` (kill-by-parent).

Comment: Thanks! Actually I need a concept way, so `pkill -P` means that it find all children by parent pid and send signals to them. Maybe there is another way to handle asynchronous signal within parent bash-script with wait alternative usage or without wait?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally I fix my problem with following approach: I setup ignore signal handler in bash-script and make it leader of process group. Then redefine SIGHUP handler in another_long_running_process and then send signal to *process group*. So bash-script and long_running_process ignore that signal, and another_long_running_process catch signal and handle it.